# Insert rows as separators in time series data

Tags: python, time-series

I'm working on a project which analyses students' click behaviors in an online course, we treat the click path as sequential data, it looks like:

```
user_id timestamp          duration_sec     Page        
545301  8/25/2020 14:49    5                home        
545301  8/25/2020 15:00    10               instructor  
545301  9/2/2020  13:33    5                home       
545301  9/8/2020  12:46    3                home        
545301  9/9/2020  11:10    3                home       
545301  9/9/2020  13:24    8                general    
545301  9/9/2020  14:33    12               zoom
```

What I want to do is add rows as separators between sub-series to indicate that the student take a break between two behavior series(i.e. the time between two clicks is very long, like longer than 3 hours). The expected data should be like this:

```
user_id timestamp          duration_sec     Page        
545301  8/25/2020 14:49    5                home        
545301  8/25/2020 15:00    10               instructor
545301  8/25/2020 15:10    99999            break
545301  9/2/2020  13:33    5                home    
545301  9/2/2020  13:38    99999            break
545301  9/8/2020  12:46    3                home
545301  9/8/2020  12:49    99999            break       
545301  9/9/2020  11:10    3                home       
545301  9/9/2020  13:24    8                general    
545301  9/9/2020  14:33    12               zoom
```

I'll be so grateful if anyone can give me some hints.

> **Update**
> I have realized this with @Abdel's help:
> first, add a column called `gap`, which indicate the time(hours) away from the next click

```py
df['gap']= (df['start_time_shift'] - df['start_time']).dt.total_seconds()/3600
```

> Second, define a function for adding breaks:

```py
def add_breaks(df):
    List_of_breaks=[]
    for i in range(len(df.index)):
        if df.gap.iloc[i] > 3: 
            List_of_breaks.append(i)
    
    for i in List_of_breaks:
        line = pd.DataFrame({'course_id':df.course_id.iloc[i],
                         "user_id": df.user_id.iloc[i], 
                         "start_time": df.end_time.iloc[i], 
                         'end_time':df.start_time_shift.iloc[i],
                         'start_time_shift':df.start_time_shift.iloc[i+1],
                         'duration_min':df.start_time_shift.iloc[i]-df.end_time.iloc[i],
                         'gap': 'gap',
                         'page':'break}, index=[i+1])
        df=pd.concat([df.iloc[:i+1], line, df.iloc[i+2:]]).reset_index(drop=True)                 
        
    return(df)
```

I modified @Abdel's answer by1) changing the filter condition to the value of gap. 2)the way of adding rows, it should be `df.iloc[:i+1], line, df.iloc[i+2:]]).reset_index(drop=True)`

Comment: How does the structure of the inserted row should be? what is (for example) the value of the `duration_min` column in the `break` row added?

Comment: @Abdel Thank you for your question, the timestamp of the new 'break' row will be timestamp + duration of the last row, the duration of break can be found by calculating the difference between the timestamp of break and next behavior.  I just leave it as 99999. Since my objective is to find the behavior sequence of each student, the duration of the break is not so important here.

Comment: I already unswered. Have a look on my answer! ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this solution, I assume that the user_id is not the index. If it is, just reset the index before starting.

First we define the "idle_time" between events by taking the difference between the timestamps, and taking into account the duration_sec (which we need to convert from number to timedelta first):

```
df['idle_time'] = df.timestamp.diff().shift(-1) - pd.to_timedelta(df.duration_sec, unit='s')

   user_id           timestamp  duration_sec        Page       idle_time
0   545301 2020-08-25 14:49:00             5        home 0 days 00:10:55
1   545301 2020-08-25 15:00:00            10  instructor 7 days 22:32:50
2   545301 2020-09-02 13:33:00             5        home 5 days 23:12:55
3   545301 2020-09-08 12:46:00             3        home 0 days 22:23:57
4   545301 2020-09-09 11:10:00             3        home 0 days 02:13:57
5   545301 2020-09-09 13:24:00             8     general 0 days 01:08:52
6   545301 2020-09-09 14:33:00            12        zoom             NaT
```

Then we grab the rows previous to the student taking a break, which in this case I defined as more than 6 hours of idle_time (but you could change it to be whatever you want):

```
pre_breaks = df[df.idle_time > pd.to_timedelta(6, unit='h')]
   user_id           timestamp  duration_sec        Page       idle_time
1   545301 2020-08-25 15:00:00            10  instructor 7 days 22:32:50
2   545301 2020-09-02 13:33:00             5        home 5 days 23:12:55
3   545301 2020-09-08 12:46:00             3        home 0 days 22:23:57
```

Then we modify these rows to be the break rows, as follows:

```
pre_breaks['timestamp'] = pre_breaks.timestamp + 
pd.to_timedelta(pre_breaks.duration_sec, 's')
pre_breaks['Page'] = 'break'
pre_breaks['duration_sec'] = pre_breaks.idle_time.apply(lambda x:x.seconds)

   user_id           timestamp  duration_sec   Page  idle_time
1   545301 2020-08-25 15:00:10         81170  break        NaN
2   545301 2020-09-02 13:33:05         83575  break        NaN
3   545301 2020-09-08 12:46:03         80637  break        NaN
```

Then we insert them in the indexes that correspond to the events where the student took a break:

```
for i in pre_breaks.index:
df.loc[i+0.5] = pre_breaks.loc[i]

     user_id           timestamp  duration_sec        Page       idle_time
0.0   545301 2020-08-25 14:49:00             5        home 0 days 00:10:55
1.0   545301 2020-08-25 15:00:00            10  instructor 7 days 22:32:50
2.0   545301 2020-09-02 13:33:00             5        home 5 days 23:12:55
3.0   545301 2020-09-08 12:46:00             3        home 0 days 22:23:57
4.0   545301 2020-09-09 11:10:00             3        home 0 days 02:13:57
5.0   545301 2020-09-09 13:24:00             8     general 0 days 01:08:52
6.0   545301 2020-09-09 14:33:00            12        zoom             NaT
1.5   545301 2020-08-25 15:00:10         81170       break             NaT
2.5   545301 2020-09-02 13:33:05         83575       break             NaT
3.5   545301 2020-09-08 12:46:03         80637       break             NaT
```

Finally, we sort the index, and reset it. We also drop the idle_time column (optional):

```
df = df.sort_index().reset_index(drop=True).drop(columns='idle_time')
```

Final result:

```
   user_id           timestamp  duration_sec        Page
0   545301 2020-08-25 14:49:00             5        home
1   545301 2020-08-25 15:00:00            10  instructor
2   545301 2020-08-25 15:00:10         81170       break
3   545301 2020-09-02 13:33:00             5        home
4   545301 2020-09-02 13:33:05         83575       break
5   545301 2020-09-08 12:46:00             3        home
6   545301 2020-09-08 12:46:03         80637       break
7   545301 2020-09-09 11:10:00             3        home
8   545301 2020-09-09 13:24:00             8     general
9   545301 2020-09-09 14:33:00            12        zoom
```

Comment: It works! thank you so much for your help, really appreciated it!

Comment: @qiweimen I'm so glad! I'd be very pleased if you marked it as best answer, I'm new and I'm building rep haha. Thank you and good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Here is my answer (to the first version of the question, since some data did change between):

> First I did build something that resembles your dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
import re

f= re.sub('\s+',',',re.sub('\n','..',"""user_id timestamp duration_min  Page        
545301  8/25/2020_14:49    8.600000         home        
545301  8/25/2020_15:00    10.100000        instructor  
545301  9/2/2020_13:33    49.700000        home       
545301  9/8/2020_12:46    223.783333       home        
545301  9/9/2020_11:10    7.633333         home       
545301  9/9/2020_13:24    69.300000        general    
545301  9/9/2020_14:33    2651.133333      zoom 
""")).replace('..','\n')

f = StringIO(f)

df= pd.read_csv(f)
df['timestamp']=df['timestamp'].str.replace('_',' ',regex=False)
df.drop(['Unnamed: 4'],axis=1, inplace=True)
df.timestamp = pd.to_datetime(df.timestamp)
print(df)
```

> Then we need to find the indices in which we have to insert the lines :

```
List_of_home_indexes=[]
for i in range(len(df.index)):
    if df.Page.iloc[i] =='home': List_of_home_indexes.append(i)
print(List_of_home_indexes)
```

> Then we insert the line after defining it, by doing a loop on the indices we found:

```
from datetime import timedelta

for i in List_of_home_indexes:
    line = pd.DataFrame({"user_id": 545301, "timestamp": df.timestamp.iloc[i]+ timedelta(seconds=1), 'duration_min':99999, 'Page':'break'}, index=[i+1])
    df=pd.concat([df.iloc[:i+1], line, df.iloc[i+1:]]).reset_index(drop=True)

print(df)
```

You get then the result you want.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! but the place that I want to insert the 'break' row is not dependents on the click on the home page, but the time gap between two adjacent clicks. For example, there's a big gap between 8/25 and 9/2, so I want to add a 'break' row here. I assume that if the time between two clicks is greater than X, the student takes a break, I will adjust your solution a little bit to achieve this purpose, anyway thank you so much for your help!